# Shift dates on the fly based on a condition using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11, 21, 31, 41, 51],
                        'date_1': ['12/30/1961', '05/29/1967', '02/03/1957', '7/27/1959', '01/13/1971'],
                        'backward': [0,120,1,2,3],
                        'forward':  [0,12,1,0,0]})
df1['date_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date_1'])
```

What I would like to do is

1) Shift forward `date_1` column based on values from the `forward` column (add dates).

2) if `forward` column has a value of `0`, then pick the value from `backward` and shift the date `backward` (subtract dates)

3) if both `forward` and `backward` are `0`, it will not make any difference to dates as we `add/subtract 0 days to date`. For coding purposes, if you still wanna know which column to pick then we can consider the `backward` column.

This is what I tried

```
df1['new_date'] = df1['date_1'].sub(pd.to_timedelta(df1['forward'],unit='d'))
df1['bool'] = df1['date_1'].eq(df1['new_date']) # i do this to find out which rows aren't changed. So I can look at backward column to subtract days for these records
df1.loc[df1.bool == True, "new_date"] = df1['date_1'].sub(pd.to_timedelta(df1['backward'],unit='d'))
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below. As you can see for the last 2 rows and the 1st row, the `forward` column had a value of 0, so we pick values from the `backward` column and `subtract the dates`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `mask` on forward to replace the 0s by minus backward column and then add `to_timedelta` this series to the date

```
df1['new_date'] = (df1['date_1'] 
                   + pd.to_timedelta(df1['forward'].mask(lambda x: x.eq(0), 
                                                         -df1['backward']), 
                                     unit='d')
                  )
print (df1)
   person_id     date_1  backward  forward   new_date
0         11 1961-12-30         0        0 1961-12-30
1         21 1967-05-29       120       12 1967-06-10
2         31 1957-02-03         1        1 1957-02-04
3         41 1959-07-27         2        0 1959-07-25
4         51 1971-01-13         3        0 1971-01-10
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. one quick question will it be also possible to output what's the value that was chosen for each subject? Meaning we know for for `person_id -21`, it was `12`. A dataframe which contains the values chosen for each person...

Comment: @TheGreat IIUC, you can create the column `df1['date_shift'] = df1['forward'].mask(lambda x: x.eq(0), -df1['backward'])`?

Comment: Can help with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635778/exclude-a-specific-date-based-on-a-condition-using-pandas